# Calculate the number of the same strings in the column - remove odd counts

Tags: r

I would like to calculate number of the same strings in the column and if the number is odd remove all the rows with such string. For example:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(
Name = c(rep("Mark", 6), rep("Tom", 8), rep("Tim", 12), rep("Greg", 3), rep("Matt", 3)),
rand = rnorm(32, 0, 1))
```

Take a look on the column `Name`. As you see `Greg` and `Matt` appear 3 times (odd number), therefore, they should be removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `table`

```
EvenNames = names(table(DF$Name))[as.vector(table(DF$Name))%%2==0]
DF = DF[DF$Name %in% EvenNames,]
```

Answer (score 3):

Solution with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df_new <- df %>% group_by(Name) %>% filter(n() %% 2 == 0)
```

Answer (score 3):

If this is based on odd/even count of unique elements in 'Name', an option with `data.table` to keep only the even count of 'Name' is

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, if(!.N%%2) .SD , by = Name]
```